# str.contains based on another column is returning values for empty strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need col1 in the dataframe to be filled based on strings in col2, such as:

```
Out[]: 
   Col2      Col1 
0  SAP       SAP     
1  Oracle    Oracle     
2            N/A     
3  SAP       SAP     
4  SF        Salesforce
```

The code works, but col1 has values that don't belong because col2 is blank. (See row 3)

```
Out[]: 
   Col2      Col1 
0  SAP       SAP     
1  Oracle    Oracle     
2            Oracle    
3  SAP       SAP     
4  SF        Salesforce
```

Tried adding a `pd.np.where(df[column2]str.contains(""), "Empty")`

But then all of column1 is filled with "Empty" and it ignores the rest.

Here's my code:

```
DF['Col1']= pd.np.where(DF['Col2'].str.contains('Oracle'), 'Oracle',
            pd.np.where(DF['Col2'].str.contains('SAP'), 'SAP',        
            pd.np.where(DF['Col2'].str.contains('SF'), 'Salesforce', 'N/A')))
```

Expected Output is:

```
Out[]: 
   Col2      Col1 
0  SAP       SAP      
1  Oracle    Oracle     
2            N/A    
3  SAP       SAP      
4  SF        Salesforce
```

Comment: `contains("")` sounds dangerous. Doesn't it return `True` for any string?

Comment: No boolean returns, it's filling all of Col1 with the "Empty" string.

Comment: That's what I'm saying, since `df[column2].str.contains("")` is all `True`, `np.where` will fill everything with `'Empty'`

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've since deleted that line but then blanks are treated as "Oracle"

Comment: `df.loc[df['Col2'].eq(""), 'Col2'] = 'Empty'`?

Comment: What is the expected output can you post?

Comment: @KarnKumar Edited with expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now getting the Data Frame you have shown, i got the fair idea of doing it in my way, there might be better additions though..

### Original DataFrame as you have shown on the comment section:

```
>>> df
              Catagory     MGA
0           Oracle IPS  Oracle
1  SAP IPS FICA Module  Oracle
2                       Oracle
3   SAAP IPS MM Module  Oracle
4         SF Lightning  Oracle
```

So, you can use `str.split()` method on the `Catagory` column by splitting them by space delimiter which will further create four new columns and since you're looking for the starting values from the `Catagory` column that will fall in the column `0` which you have to opt.

```
>>> df['Catagory'].str.split(' ', expand=True)
        0          1     2       3
0  Oracle        IPS  None    None
1     SAP        IPS  FICA  Module
2               None  None    None
3    SAAP        IPS    MM  Module
4      SF  Lightning  None    None
```

As you see above column `0` still have an empty cell which we will use `replace()` method , However altogether you are transforming the another value `SF` to `Salesforce` hence that also needs to be replaced So, i will use a dict method with `replace` to achieve both in one go.

### Solution:

```
vals = {'':'Non-MGA', 'SF':'Salesforce'}

>>> df = df.assign(MGA_NEW=df['Catagory'].str.split(' ', expand=True)[0].replace(vals)).drop(columns={'MGA'})
>>> df
              Catagory     MGA_NEW
0           Oracle IPS      Oracle
1  SAP IPS FICA Module         SAP
2                          Non-MGA
3   SAAP IPS MM Module        SAAP
4         SF Lightning  Salesforce
```

Since, we don't required the other columns produced from `split()` hence i dropped them and used `assign()` method to assign back the values to a new column `MGA_NEW` and eventually dropped the original column `MGA` that's not required.

If you want to retain the column name `MGA` again you can do that..

```
>>> df.rename(columns={'MGA_NEW':'MGA'}, inplace=True)
>>> df
              Catagory         MGA
0           Oracle IPS      Oracle
1  SAP IPS FICA Module         SAP
2                          Non-MGA
3   SAAP IPS MM Module        SAAP
4         SF Lightning  Salesforce
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Unfortunately, I need col1 to use a different term based on strings in col2 containing certain 'keywords'.

Your code works, but not exactly what I need, I appreciate it.

Comment: NP, i understand..  can you show the actual dataFrame  looks like so, we can match the expected output?

Comment: I need to search in "Category" column for matching strings, and based on that string, fill "MGA" column.

This is what the current DF output looks like:

https://i.imgur.com/l6M40Kq.png

This is what I need it to look like:

https://i.imgur.com/18wUT3D.png

Comment: I ended up using part of your solution, mostly the dictionary idea without splitting the data. 

I cloned the category column and applied the dictionary with .replace method.

Thank you

Comment: Glad it helped, even you can place the solution you applied at the pot or as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `str.contains("")` you can think of using **regex**. The following code replaces all the empty strings in the whole dataframe with the word "`Empty`" using regex:

```
df.replace(r'^\s*$', 'Empty', regex=True, inplace=True)
```